# Microsoft VS - Access

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access

I'm having a problem with `access-VS` it's ways Variable not defined can anyone help me?

This is the code that i'm working on: (am a newbie)

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnLogin_Click()
    Dim rs As Recordset

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl1Employees", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)

    rs.FindFirst "UserName='" & Me.txtUserNAme & "'"

    If rs.NoMatch = True Then
        Me.lblWrongUser.Visible = True
        Me.txtUserNAme.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Me.lblWrongUser.Visible = False

    If rs!Password <> Nz(Me.txtPassword, "") Then
        Me.lblWrongPass.Visible = True
        Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Me.lblWrongPass.Visible = False
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMenu"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: *Which* variable?

Comment: i dont know lol , but the error is making Private Sub btnLogin_Click() in YELLOW and dbOpenSnapShot in Blue

Comment: Could it be a typo: _tblEmployees_ (not tbl1Employees).

Comment: @Gustav thanks for you replay. the table name is tbl1Employees

Comment: Then try: `Dim rs As DAO.Recordset`. And/or leave out the options of OpenRecordset.

Comment: i added "Dim rs As DAO.Recordset" and i get another error "user-define type not defined" at DAO.Recordset

Comment: In your original code, replace `dbOpenSnapshot` with `dbOpenTable` and test it. Does this raise any errors?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns yeh im still geting "variable not Defined" and dbOpenTable in YELLOW

Comment: Ok, second try, replace `dbopensnapshot` with number `1` and test it

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Nah its not working now im geting dbReadOnly in BLUE, is there anyway to contact with you ill send you the access file and you can check it.

Comment: No need of that for now. Your problem is that reserved words of Access like `dbOpenSnapshot ` or `dbOpenTable ` or `dbReadOnly` are not reconigzed. So you must use NUMBERS instead of words. You will have to navigate MSDN website looking for each numeric value of what you want. For example: `dbOpenSnapshot ` is 4, `dbOpenTable` is 1 ([You can read this here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/office/ff195231.aspx)). Your command should be `CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl1Employees", 4, 4)` ([Read more here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/office/ff192649.aspx).

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Numbers are working now fine but now i got an error at Set ra =

Comment: What is `Set ra = –`?